# Synchronizing images from two different cameras

Tags: c, synchronization, camera

I am receiving images from two different cameras, having different frame rates and resolutions.  One of the cameras (the smart camera) works as a controller. It receives images from other camera and its own image sensor and then saves the image pairs on the on-board memory. Here, I have a problem. I have to do stereo matching with each pair of images. Hence, the images should be perfectly synchronized (just a few milliseconds apart). I point both the cameras to an on-screen stop watch and capture images just to see how far, in time, they are from each other. It turned out to be disappointing that neither they are synchronized, neither the time offset between a single pair is constant. I am working on linux and programming in C. I tried two posix threads for capturing images from individual cameras. The first thread cam1() signals the other thread cam2() before it starts image capture. Therefore, the two image captures are supposed to start at the same time. But this doesn't work either. I would really appreciate any solution in this regard.

Comment: I'm no camera expert, so what follows is just my ignorant opinion. This is not going to be simple since kernel drivers are involved. You don't know which kind of delays they impose. Plus, the hardware itself may introduce delays. I think you have to stream video from both cams using the same frame rate, and find the best temporal offset between the streams (and probably keep reevaluating the offset, as frame rate may drift).

Answer (score 1):

Clock synchronization is a pretty challenging issue in every sensor network. I am not an expert, however there are some solutions you can try.

Firstly, [n.m. is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501919/synchronizing-images-from-two-different-cameras#comment13577518_10501919)! software synchronization is very hard in high FPS situations where you need to control the FPS (you need to have the same FPS), the exposure, timestamps etc between the image acquiring of the two cameras. Camera synchronization is commonly done externally known as external trigger and sync I/O.

In externally synchronized cameras the two clocks aren't always the same. The camera clock crystal's always have a drift which is specified by design. you can calculate how much time it takes for two images to drift in a distinguishable manner and reset the clocks. I have used AVT cameras for some time. [The company proposes](http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/fileadmin/content/PDF/Support/Application_Notes/ApplNote-timestamp.pdf):

> Users interested in synching the camera Timestamp to another clock
>   should note that the camera clock will drift from the other clock, and
>   therefore will need to be periodically re-synched by resetting the
>   Timestamp.

If you have low FPS and you can know the dropped frames count at any time, you can synchronize with the (increasing) annotation named Frame Count of each frame.

If you have stereo calibrated images, certain features in the default camera's images (define one arbitrarily or just the one that triggers the other), may lay on/close to the [epipolar lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry) that cross the other camera. Thus epipolar lines may introduce a certain invariant in your program logic to pair features (detected blobs).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. My problem is that I have two entirely different cameras, having different frame rates, exposure times, capturing mechanism etc. Somehow, I have managed to synchronize the images using two different threads for capturing. One of the cameras, the GigE, now works in triggered mode. The other camera, the smart cam, sends a trigger to GigE camera and then receives image from it and from its own sensor. However, to match the frames, I do have to skip some frames from the smart camera. Due to frame rate drift, the skipping sometimes is not accurate.

Comment: Now, 90% of the images are perfectly synchronized. The rest have a constant offset. The problem is that I have no way to determine how much and when would the drift occur. So, sometimes, when I skip two frames, I get an offset. Is this frame rate drift found in all the cameras?